# how to set variable in rule of makefile

Tags: xml, unix, makefile

Issue : Target isn't getting build because dependency list is getting built at run-time. How to specify dependency list if while declaring variable files are not present.

How to redefine variable VIP_FOFs VIP_XMLs from recipe(rule) ?

Code: 
(*.fof files are generated by script temp.pl from target copy_fof) so is there a way to declare following VIP_FOFs and VIP_XMLs from recipe of copy_fof ?

```
VIP_FOFs := $(wildcard $(RECITAL_PATH)/vip_xml/xml_generation/*.fof)

VIP_XMLs = $(VIP_FOFs:.fof=.xml)

all: copy_fof $(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml

copy_fof:
        `perl temp.pl`

%.xml: %.fof
    rpfImport \
        --view rtl_simulation \
        --append_log \
        --log $(RECITAL_PATH)/logs/rpfImport.log \
        --format fof  --vlnv ,,$(notdir $(basename $< .fof)), \
        --output $@  $< ;

$(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml: $(VIP_XMLs)  
    @echo "#  generating catalog.xml "; \
    rpfCatalog --add $(VIP_XMLs)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, it's hard to understand anything.

Comment: Thanks to @Kusalanada. Hope it's clear now

Comment: No, it's not clear at all. You do not clearly explain what you are asking for, what result you currently have, why it is not satisfactory, and last but not least, what you show it is not even valid make syntax. Please help us helping you.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Hope it's clear now. Thanks

Comment: I have a hypothesis about what you want, but it is difficult even to state it and ask for confirmation, when the makefile is this complicated. I suggest you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Beta:I have few lines that will explain flow of code .. Hope it helps ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` is intended to rebuild only what needs to be, based on descriptions of target / pre-requisites dependencies. If, each time you invoke `make`, the `*.fof` targets are re-built by your `temp.pl` script, `make` is rather useless. In order to rebuild everything every time, simply adapt your perl script to finish the job and do not use `make`.

In the following I will thus assume that, as long as the `temp.pl` script does not change, there is no need to rebuild the `*.fof`. I will also assume that you cannot predict the name of the `*.fof` files, which seems to be your main problem.

To solve this problem you can use recursive make (make calling make):

```
VIP_FOFs := $(wildcard $(RECITAL_PATH)/vip_xml/xml_generation/*.fof)
VIP_XMLs := $(patsubst %.fof,%.xml,$(VIP_FOFs))

.PHONY: all

all: copy_fof
    $(MAKE) $(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml

copy_fof: temp.pl
    perl temp.pl
    touch $@

$(VIP_XMLs): %.xml: %.fof
    rpfImport \
        --view rtl_simulation \
        --append_log \
        --log $(RECITAL_PATH)/logs/rpfImport.log \
        --format fof  --vlnv ,,$(notdir $(basename $< .fof)), \
        --output $@  $< ;

$(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml: $(VIP_XMLs)  
    @echo "#  generating catalog.xml "; \
    rpfCatalog --add $(VIP_XMLs)
```

When you will invoke make, it will build the `all` phony target. As `all` is phony, its recipe will always be executed. If the `copy_fof` empty file is newer than the `temp.pl` script, there will be nothing to do for the pre-requisites of `all`, the `*.fof` files are up to date. Else, the `temp.pl` script will be run, creating the `*.fof` files and creating or modifying the `copy_fof` empty file to indicate that the job has been done.

Then, the `all` recipe will be run, `make` will be invoked a second time to build `$(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml`. This time, the `*.fof` files exist and the `VIP_FOFs` and `VIP_XMLs` variables will take the values you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Renaud Pacalet ... use of recursive make solves my problem.